# Ionic how to integrate screensharing in mobile using Twilio

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, twilio, capacitor, screensharing

I was integrated the video calling with room creations using Twilio npm package after that I got another requirement to implement screen sharing functionality the below code working fine for the web browsers but during the video call in mobile app is not working, if any help provided how to do that implementation with Twilio or without Twilio will be appreciated.

```
mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ constraints }).then(stream =\> {

  this.screenTrack = new LocalVideoTrack(stream.getTracks()\[0\],);

  room.localParticipant.publishTrack(this.screenTrack);

  this.screenshared(this.screenTrack);

  this.shareText = 'Stop sharing';

  this.screenTrack.mediaStreamTrack.onended = () =\> { this.shareScreen() };

}).catch((err) =\> {

  console.log(err);

  alert('Could not share the screen.');

});
```

Comment: You say it's not working but you haven't showed anything that indicates that. You need to provide more info such as the console logs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the method `mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()` does not work on WebView Android and some other mobile browsers. You can check the browser compatibility for `getDisplayMedia()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia#browser_compatibility).

Please note that `getDisplayMedia()` may not be available on all mobile browsers or WebView implementations. You may need to find an alternative solution or consider using a different approach for capturing the display on mobile devices.